# How to get a Windows 8.1 iso for clean install with a Single Language key?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

I only have a Windows 8 Single Language key purchased. They mostly sell that version in  my country. But I need to perform a clean install of Windows 8.1. How can I do this? How to get the ISO? I can't install 8.1 PRO ISO with a generic key and they use the SL key to activate right?

Comment: @techie007 please read my question carefully and do some research before marking as duplicate. The Single Language version of Windows 8 won't work that way.

Answer (score 1):

There is no legal way to get such an ISO. Reinstall your Windows 8.0, install all updates, open the store and install Windows 8.1. Now install the large 8.1 Update from Windows Update and after you did this, capture your own [recovery WIM with recimg](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/01/04/refresh-and-reset-your-pc.aspx):

```
recimg -CreateImage C:\RefreshImage
```

so that you can [refresh the PC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc) the next time you run into issues.

Comment: You can actually download the single language ISOs directly.

Just head over  to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows8ISO (from Mac or Linux, or change your user agent so it doesn't redirect you to download manager), and download the ISO. I've just updated my W8 oem laptop's license to W10 that way. Just don't add any CD key whenever asked, it both acticates W8.1, and (after official upgrade procedure) W10.